# Finding acronyms in a string via splitting

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently writing a script that is supposed to be able to see whether a string matches a given partial acronym.

In this case, I'm taking each element from a list which is a string and summing each of the characters in each string within the list.

From there I want to compare the letters from the candidate word with the letters of each word in the list.

Once complete, the first letter of the candidate word is stripped off and then the comparison is done on the next string in the list with the newly truncated string.

So ideally,

```
1st iteration: 

input: 
word_list = ['toronto', 'dominion', 'bank']
candidate = 'tdbank'

output:

1 matching characters
new candidate word = 'dbank'

2nd iteration:

input:
word_list = ['dominion', 'bank']
candidate = 'dbank'

output:

1 matching characters
new candidate word = 'bank'

3rd iteration:

input:
word_list = ['bank']
candidate = 'bank'

output:

4 matching characters
new candidate word = 'bank'

total_matches = 6
```

Iterating until the length of the list is reached. Each matching count is returned and summed so summing the two example outputs the total count would be 7. This is the code I've written for it so far, I can't get it to save each number and sum it to a final integer as well as well as to continuously truncate the candidate letter.

```
def compare(a, b):
        count = 0
        for x, y in zip(a, b):
            if x == y:
                count += 1
        return count 

init_sum = len(''.join(init_name_list))
c = 0

for i,j in enumerate(init_name_list):
    c = compare(j, candidate)
    t_candidate = candidate[1:]
    c = compare(j, t_candidate)
    sim = c/init_sum
```

This isn't the most efficient way of doing it, but I would just like to get it working first, so if anyone knows a faster/better way ideally without creating a package dependency that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the python for what I think you're trying to do

```
c = []
for word in init_name_list:
    c.append(compare(word, candidate))
    candidate = candidate[c[-1]:] #truncates string
sim = sum(c) / init_sum
```

Comment: Perfect, now to implement a backwards implementation!